# Mastering NLP: Reading List

Tags: nlp, reference-request, books

I've searched the web and there are hundreds of recommendations on what to read. The time moves on and new better quality techniques are published, so I would like to know what is relevant in 2018?

My background is 4 years of BSc in Maths & Stats (top uni) + 1 year of role in Data Science (building predictive models, no NLP).

If possible, please separate it into sections/readings, e.g.

- Background (History, e.g. philosophical)
- Theoretical (Mathematics)
- Practical (Using Tensorflow and other NLP libraries to build algorithms)

---

I have a few side projects that I would like to do:

*Build an algorithm which answers multiple choice questions*

E.g. given a question:

Which is not a fruit?
1) Apple 2) Cucumber

I would like NLP to understand negation, and find that the topic of the question is fruit. Then I'd probably incorporate Google Search API or something.

---

*Categorise a list of 'keyword' searches into categories.*

Let's take google which probably has something like this, it categorises every keyword and gives recommendations. Given a list of 10,000 searches, I would like to categorise them into N categories, based on similarity (not just how similar the words are, but including synonyms).

Comment: There are a couple of closed questions on Stack Overflow that might be of interest here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212219/what-are-good-starting-points-for-someone-interested-in-natural-language-processi
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233435/machine-learning-and-natural-language-processing

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest instead of trying to get many sources, get one source that goes through concepts first (fairly robustly), then seek out sources to refine or deepen your knowledge. One source comes from Stanford's NLP group, and is [Introduction to Information Retrieval](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html).  The only thing I don't like about this books is that it tends to orient documents as columns (where data science has more or less agreed that they are rows), but that's a pretty trivial concern (as long as you can take a matrix transpose).  Aside from that, this book has excellent explanations, and the proper depth and breadth to be considered an exhaustive base for NLP.

Answer (score 4):

[not a book but...] Definitely check out https://github.com/sebastianruder/NLP-progress for a self-updating list of relevant state-of-the-art literature in the field of NLP and its subfields.

As per the side projects that you mentioned, you might want to check e.g.

- https://github.com/sebastianruder/NLP-progress/blob/master/question_answering.md
- (possibly) https://github.com/sebastianruder/NLP-progress/blob/master/taxonomy_learning.md

Check also recommendations that were given on SO,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233435/machine-learning-and-natural-language-processing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212219/what-are-good-starting-points-for-someone-interested-in-natural-language-processi

Comment: ...and http://newsletter.ruder.io/ could be a newsletter of interest too.

Answer (score 3):

*[Natural Language Processing in Action: Understanding, Analyzing, and Generating Text with Python](https://www.manning.com/books/natural-language-processing-in-action)* is a new practical textbook that covers all the latest (2019) topics.

Answer (score 2):

**Collected from Different Sources**

NLP industry is expected to grow from USD 10.2 billion in 2019 to USD 26.4 billion by 2024. Here are a few resources to get started with NLP and be a part of this highly awesome domain.

- NLP course by Yandex School of Data Analytics: https://lnkd.in/fePhndv
- State of the Art #NLP Innovations: https://lnkd.in/fbGkS_a
- Deep Learning for NLP: https://lnkd.in/fWkGCbR
- Fast AI NLP Course: https://lnkd.in/fPCcJAZ
- Awesome NLP Journey: https://lnkd.in/fk7edUt
- Resources from Top NLP Conferences: https://lnkd.in/fiy-rhE
- NLP with #python: https://lnkd.in/fBbRkd9
- NLP with Deep Learning: https://lnkd.in/fCvRyCi
- Curated Resources for NLP: https://lnkd.in/fkCcu_3
- NLP Tutorial for #deeplearning Researchers: https://lnkd.in/fSJ34yR

**Articles**

- All kinds of Text Classification Models: https://lnkd.in/fZ4_zq6
- Open-source NLP research library, built on PyTorch: https://lnkd.in/ft9rxyE
- State-of-the-art NLP for TensorFlow 2.0 and PyTorch: https://lnkd.in/fYcNwYU
- NLP for the next decade: https://lnkd.in/fi78EBC

> **19 Great Articles About Natural Language Processing (NLP):**
>
> 1. [Structuring Unstructured Big Data via Indexation](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/5-easy-steps-to-structure-highly-unstructured-big-data)
> 2. [Your Guide to Natural Language Processing (NLP)](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/your-guide-to-natural-language-processing-nlp)
> 3. [Comparison of Top 6 Python NLP Libraries](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/comparison-of-top-6-python-nlp-libraries)
> 4. [Text Classification & Sentiment Analysis tutorial](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-tutorial-blog)
> 5. [Deep Learning Research Review: Natural Language Processing](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/deep-learning-research-review-week-3-natural-language-processing)
> 6. [10 Common NLP Terms Explained for the Text Analysis Novice](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/10-common-nlp-terms-explained-for-the-text-analysis-novice)
> 7. [Temporal Convolutional Nets Take Over from RNNs for NLP Predictions](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/temporal-convolutional-nets-tcns-take-over-from-rnns-for-nlp-pred)
> 8. [How I used NLP (Spacy) to screen Data Science Resumes](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/how-i-used-nlp-spacy-to-screen-data-science-resumes)
> 9. [Data Science Reveals Trump Tweets are Written by Two People](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/data-science-reveals-trump-tweets-are-written-by-two-people)
> 10. [Simple introduction to Natural Language Processing](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/see-this-simple-introduction-to-natural-language-processing-nlp)
> 11. [An NLP Approach to Analyzing Twitter, Trump, and Profanity](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/an-nlp-approach-to-analyzing-twitter-trump-and-profanity)
> 12. [A Natural Language Processing (NLP) Approach to Data Exploration](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/video/a-natural-language-processing-nlp-approach-to-data-exploration)
> 13. [Python NLTK Tools List for Natural Language Processing](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/python-nlp-tools)
> 14. [NLP app to find great available domain names](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/nlp-app-to-find-great-available-domain-names)
> 15. [Scaling an NLP problem without using a ton of hardware](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/short-story-on-scaling-an-nlp-problem-without-using-a-ton-of)
> 16. [Analyzing the structure and effectiveness of news headlines](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/analyzing-the-structure-and-effectiveness-of-news-headlines-using)
> 17. [Seven tricky sentences for NLP and text mining algorithms](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/seven-tricky-sentences-for-nlp-and-text-mining-algorithms)
> 18. [Overview of Artificial Intelligence and Role of NLP](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/overview-of-artificial-intelligence-and-role-of-natural-language)
> 19. [Text Classification & Sentiment Analysis tutorial](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-tutorial-blog)

**For Beginners**

> ### NLTK
>
> - Bible of NLP is [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (Natural Language Toolkit). They have a free [ebook](http://www.nltk.org/book/) as well.
>
> ### Books
>
> - [Natural Language Processing with Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516499.do)
> - [Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/foundations-statistical-natural-language-processing) - Its very important to have statistical understanding to apply NLP.
> - [Handbook of Natural Language Processing](http://www.springer.com/in/book/9781441977120)
>
> ### Blog Series
>
> - [Dive into NLTK](http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-i-getting-started-with-nltk)
> - [NLPers](https://nlpers.blogspot.in/)
>
> ### Youtube videos
>
> - [Dan Jurafsky & Chris Manning: Natural Language Processing](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6397E4B26D00A269)
>
> ## Deep Learning
>
> ### Blog
>
> - [Deep Learning, NLP, and Representations](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-NLP-RNNs-Representations/)
> - [Word Embeddings 3 part series by Sabastian Ruder](http://ruder.io/word-embeddings-1/index.html)
>
> ### Tutorials by Frameworks
>
> - [Deep Learning for NLP with Pytorch](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/deep_learning_nlp_tutorial.html)
> - [Text Processing in Keras](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html)
> - [Sequence-to-Sequence Models in Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq)
> - [Vector Representations of Words -wordtovec](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec)
>
> ### MOOCs
>
> [Stanford CS224n: Natural Language Processing with Deep Learning](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/)
>
> ### Python libraries
>
> [Spacy - Industrial-Strength Natural Language Processing](https://spacy.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked/read/watched countless sources on NLP, but at the end only two really made the difference:

1. The best book ever on NLP: **Speech and Language Processing** by Dan Jurafsky and James H. Martin. The authors are making all its content available for free [on their academic website](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/). This contains 99.999% of the NLP notions needed in a whole ML career, and they keep it constantly updated.
2. Stanford University course on **Natural Language Processing with Deep Learning**, by Chris Manning et al. This is a very intense course that explains everything from basics to very advanced attention RNNs. Quite challenging at some points, but it's so dense of extremely high quality content. They put all the 2019 course [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3FW7Lu3i5Jsnh1rnUwq_TcylNr7EkRe6).

There's so many stuff around that I found on GitHub, books, blogs, ... you name it. But at the end what really made the difference have been these two above.

Comment: Correct link to CS224N of 2019 is https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoROMvodv4rOhcuXMZkNm7j3fVwBBY42z (the linked here is older)

Comment: Thank you, yes they keep updating the course page every time a new course starts. However, all the editions are still available on YouTube